# Use of MERGE to insert patterns of nodes and edges

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to insert patterns (nodes and edges) using merge. Using the demo movies graph, I'm sending the following cypher query: the movie exists, I'd like to create the User node and the edge in one query.

```
MERGE (top:Movie { title:'Top Gun' })<-[:viewed]-(user:User {Name:'Pierre'}) 
ON CREATE SET user.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp()
RETURN user,top;
```

"MERGE needs at least some part of the pattern to already be known. Please provide values for one of: user, top"

Actually, top exits, I can't figure out what's wrong in my query. Thanks for your help.
Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
MATCH (top:Movie { title:'Top Gun' })
MERGE (top)<-[:viewed]-(user:User {Name:'Pierre'}) 
ON CREATE SET user.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp()
RETURN user,top;
```

or this for creates:

```
MERGE (top:Movie { title:'Top Gun' })
MERGE (user:User {Name:'Pierre'}) 
ON CREATE SET user.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp()
MERGE (top)<-[:viewed]-(user) 
RETURN user,top;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Now that this works, I'd like to use merge to insert patterns in the database in one command. Still with that movies graph, I'm not able to use the same insert commands with a larger set. Therefore I was wondering if I could use MERGE to create / merge a pattern consisting of a movie, actors, director, producer, and corresponding relationships in one command, taking care of existing nodes?

Comment: MATCH (m:Movie {title:'The Matrix'}), (keanu:Person {Name:'Keanu Reeves'}), (carrie:Person {name:'Carrie-Anne Moss') MERGE (keanu)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m), (carrie)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m) RETURN m, keanu, carrie

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work apparently due to the comma in the pattern definition. Is it possible to create such a pattern in one command, or should I split the code in CREATE nodes hence CREATE relationship using node identifiers?